# Releasing consumed memory after using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-memory

I'm developing an application containing 100s of sound effects.
after playing some of the sounds the application force closes. I understood that the problem would be consuming all the available space of the memory. I tried using Release() method but after this method is called I'm not able to play the sound again.
I also tried using onDestroy() method to set the object of the mediaplayer to null but since these kind of objects must be final I can't do this.
What is your suggestion?
Here is my code:

```
final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (i[0] == false)
            {

                mp1.start();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "horn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop_button);

                i[0] = true;

            }
            else
            {

                mp1.pause();
                mp1.seekTo(0);

                b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.horn);

                i[0] = false;

            }

        }
    });

    mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

            b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.horn);

        }
    });
```

Comment: `the application force closes` care to show the stack trace?

Comment: may be [`SoundPool`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) is more appropriate for you?

Comment: could you post your crash log?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

You can call release() in OnDestroy() method.

```
 @Override
     public void onDestroy(){
     super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
     }
```